# Intel i5 memory consistency model?

Tags: memory, x86, intel, lock-free, memory-barriers

How to check which memory consistency model does Intel i5 have? I have been searching for Macs and Intel, and it seems impossible to find. Any tips on how to search for this information?

Comment: Do you mean the [x86 memory model](https://www.msully.net/blog/2015/02/25/the-x86-memory-model/)? This does not really vary across models; nor is it clear what MacOS would have to do with this.

Answer (score 2):

Memory ordering rules for different Intel processors are now described in the Intel [SDM](https://software.intel.com/sites/default/files/managed/39/c5/325462-sdm-vol-1-2abcd-3abcd.pdf), volume 3A, chapter 8, section 8.2 "Memory Ordering". There used to be an official [whitepaper](http://www.cs.cmu.edu/~410-f10/doc/Intel_Reordering_318147.pdf) on the subject, now only available from non-oficial sources.

Note that information published in different revisions of the SDM from 2006 and later had been changing. An overview of what was stated by x86 memory ordering independently by Intel and AMD can be found [here](http://spinroot.com/spin/Doc/course/x86_tso.pdf).